# Inject new SMS event on Android

Tags: android

I’m working on an app for Android. Is it possible to inject an event, so the phone thinks It just revived a new SMS. So it gives you a notification and everything. Not just put the new sms in the inbox.

Still cant get this to work, im thinking something like:

```
Intent a = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
a.putExtra("tlf", "123");
startActivity(a);
```

And then some :) Any one?

Comment: Still cant get this to work, im thinking someting like  Intent a = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
              a.putExtra("tlf", "123");
             
                 startActivity(a);

Comment: any progress? I could use this as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call an SMS_RECEIVED intent....

here's some more info how sms_received intent works
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/

Answer (score -1):

To get SMS notification, use [this link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android). "**Check Receiving SMS Messages**"

To abort messages in Android in Receiver class, set abortBroadcast() and in Manifest.xml, set below code in SMSReceiver:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is for receiving messages. Not for making the phone think it has received one..